# How do I convert old PostScript files created with dvips to searchable PDFs?

Tags: pdf, postscript

I am puzzled as to how to replace Type 3 bitmap fonts contained in a series of old PostScript files with more modern, Type 1 scalable fonts.   My goal is to convert the PS files into high quality, searchable PDFs, which is not possible with the Type 3 fonts in place.  All of the PS files in question were created during the 1990's with version of LaTeX and dvips (version 5.58 or earlier), and the LaTeX source files are now lost.

CTAN has a Perl program, pkfix, that claims to be able to replace the Type 3 with Type 1 fonts for the PS files that were created with dvips (version 5.58 or newer).  However, when I attempt to use this program on a file created by this version of dvips, I received the following error message:

> Warning: dvips version 5.58 does not generate the required font comments!

After this I tried using another script, pkfix-helper, as a way of cleaning up the PS files for processing by pkfix.  However, I have not been successful here either.  The following is the output that I receive at the Terminal when I try to process a file:

> Reading foobar94.ps ... done.
>   Number of Type 3 fonts encountered: 5
>   Bitmapped fonts are typeset at 300 DPI.
>   Finding character widths ... done.
>   Reading TFM files ... done (0 TFMs in 0 scaling variations).
>   pkfix-helper.pl: No TFM files were processed successfully

I should note that I am running Mac OS 10.6.4, and my TeX installation is MacTeX 2010.  In fact, I upgraded from MacTeX 2009, thinking that a newer version of tftopl, the program pkfix-helper invokes in order to process the TFM files, might solve the problem.  However, I continue to get the same error.Blockquote

Comment: It looks like `pkfix-helper` cannot find your TFM (TeX) fonts. This typically happens if your TeX installation is not set up properly. What does running `tftopl cmr10.tfm cmr10.pl` do when you run that manually?

Comment: I suspect your problem may be in that error message. While it may be obvious to you what fonts and characters are in use, the computer needs something it can understand. The error message suggests that the information required is fundamentally not available in the DVI files you have. (I've never tried what you're suggesting, so I am speculating.)

Comment: @Joseph: that is where pkfix-helper comes in, it generates and uses a tfm width database to deduce the missing information. But that only works if it succeeds in filling that database, of course. The '0 TFMs in 0 scaling variations' indicates that it fails in that stage

Comment: @Taco: As I said, I've not ever tried to do this!

Comment: @Taco I do suspect there is something wrong with my TeX installation, since this is the output I get from the command you suggested: warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /usr/bin:/usr:/:/usr/bin/share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/share/texmf-local/web2c://share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/texmf-local/web2c://texmf-local/web2c:/usr/bin/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/share/texmf/web2c://share/texmf/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf/web2c:/usr/texmf/web2c://texmf/web2c.
tftopl: fatal: tfm file `cmr10.tfm' not found.

Comment: @Kenny I suspected as much, your mactex installation appears to be broken. I don't know how to help with that, sorry.

Comment: @Taco Rather than delve into my Mac TeX installation to fix the problem, I tried using pkfix-helper on another computer on which I have Ubuntu Linux installed.  Everything works fine there, and I was able to convert the PS files in question to searchable PDFs.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: This looks like a 'too localised' question: clearly the issues here is down to one particular PC: I'm closing.

Comment: A note to moderators: I request that this question not be deleted. I found it enormously useful to search for the question in the title and encounter "pkfix" as the answer (in the body of the question).

Comment: Seconding ShreevatsaR

Comment: Third ShreevatsaR

Comment: In my case, the texlive system was a basic installation. Installing the package `fontware` that contained the `tftopl` tool solved the problem.